# How can I test wether my OCXO VCO is working fine?

Tags: clock, crystal, testing, vco

I recently bought a PTOC32227 OCXO [(datasheet)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.analysir.com/downloads/PTOC32227%2520specs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi99diW4d_lAhWy4YUKHXCKA0YQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3xBxZ2pR0tYehVVzZaUgDd&cshid=1573394421451) from eBay (secondhand). It is supposed to output a square wave at 10MHz. However, it is a part of a bigger circuit that is not working properly and it seems to me that the failing component may be the OCXO.

I took it apart from the rest of the board, and connected its VS pin to +5V, GND to ground and measured the HF pin with an oscilloscope (left the VC pin not connected). This is the output:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Shouldn't it be an square wave? How can I determine then if the OCXO is working properly?

Thank you!

Edit: my oscilloscope BW is 100MHz, so it should not be a problem in the measurement

Edit 2: new measurements with my probe in x10 mode seem fine! Thanks!

[image: New screenshot]

Comment: One thing to remember is that a 100MHz scope does only measure up to 100MHz sinusodial signals with a 3dB attenuation. A square wave contains many more harmonica and will therefore look distorted when measured with a too low bandwidth.

Comment: @jakob Well, but for this measurement I am using its full BW, and 100MHz should be able to measure well the first harmonics, so that the wave looks more like a square, isn't it?

Comment: Are you driving the 'scope input directly through a coax cable? Or perhaps you're using a X1 probe position? The coax capacitance may give you grief. Try a 10X probe.